# Aws Cognito Oauth2: Refresh token rotation

Tags: oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, refresh-token

We're using Aws Cognito with Oauth 2.0 and we're wondering, if cognito supports Refresh Token Rotation according to the Oauth 2.0 specification (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819):

*The basic idea is to change the refresh token value with every refresh request in order to detect attempts to obtain access tokens using old refresh tokens*

When we're using the Aws .net sdk to refresh our tokens:

```
await user.StartWithRefreshTokenAuthAsync(authRequestRefresh).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

...we're not getting a new refresh token back. The only way to get a new refresh token, is by doing a new login:

```
await user.StartWithSrpAuthAsync(authRequest).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Thanks for your help!

Kind regards,
Peter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cognito doesn't support refresh token rotation. You can however change the number of days a refresh token stays valid for an app client.